# Python Pandas CVS File: Slicing Values and Removing Lines with Missing Values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I read "data.csv" file and has 2 columns.

For "code" columns, I would like to slice the value string and put back only last 2 digit(alphabet) of code into columns.

For each rows, if either "username" and "code" value is missing, I would like to remove the row from the list.

```
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv("data.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols = ['username, 'code'])
print(dt)
```

What I have now

```
username  code
Chris     AB-12-DF
Jake      
Rebecca   JH-34-TY
          LK-49-RT
```

Expected Output

```
username  code
Chris     DF    
Rebecca   TY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the empty cells are `""` strings:

```py
df = df[~df.eq("").any(axis=1)]
df["code"] = df["code"].str.rsplit("-", n=1).str[-1]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  username code
0    Chris   DF
2  Rebecca   TY
```

Comment: Thank you. Also I realized I have some "NaN" in "code" columns, how can I remove those as well?

Comment: @KojiE Try `df.dropna(inplace=True)`